# Enforce a foreign-key constraint to columns of same table

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, self-reference, insert-into

How to enforce a constraint of foreign key on columns of same table in SQL while entering values in the following table:

**employee**:

- empid number,
- manager number (must be an existing employee)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME (
    `empid_number`    int     (  11) NOT NULL auto_increment,   
    `employee`        varchar ( 100) NOT NULL               ,
    `manager_number`  int     (  11) NOT NULL               ,
     PRIMARY KEY  (`empid_number`),
     CONSTRAINT `manager_references_employee`
     FOREIGN KEY (`manager_number`) REFERENCES (`empid_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: somewhat...! Any other methods/suggestions for oracle?

Comment: I never tried, but I think giving the TABLE_NAME instead of "parent_table_name" should work!!

Comment: That's not a valid statement for Oracle

Comment: I suggested for MySql. As said, I don't have any idea about oracle.

Comment: @popstack why did you select a MySQL-only answer for an Oracle question? You should unselect this answer and select the other answer by Ben.

Answer (score 23):

Oracle call this a self-referential integrity constraint. The documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c22integ.htm) for a description,

You create a self-referential constraint in the same manner you would a normal one:

```
alter table employees
  add constraint employees_emp_man_fk
      foreign key ( manager_no )
      references employees ( emp_id )
   on delete set null
      ;
```

I'm assuming that your `manager_no` is nullable. I've added set null here as a `delete cascade` would probably wipe out a significant amount of your table.

I can't think of a better way of doing this. Deleting a manager should not result in the deletion of all their employees so you have to `set null` and have a trigger on the table to alert you to anyone with no manager.

I always like [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/index.php) site, which is good for simple references. and don't forget to have an index on the FK as well or [Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156435031319) will yell at you :-).

One can also utilise standard Oracle syntax to create a self-referential FK in the create table statement, which would look like the following.

```
create table employees
 ( emp_id number
 , other_columns ...
 , manager_no number
 , constraint employees_pk 
    primary key (emp_id)
 , constraint employees_man_emp_fk
    foreign key ( manager_no )
    references employees ( emp_id )
    on delete set null
 );
```

**EDIT:**

In answer to @popstack's comment below:

Whilst you can do this in one statement not being able to alter a table is a fairly ridiculous state of affairs. You should definitely analyze a table that you're going to be selecting from and you will still want an index on the foreign key ( and possibly more columns and / or more indexes ) otherwise whenever you use the foreign key you're going to do a full table scan. See my link to asktom above.

If you're unable to alter a table then you should, in descending order of importance.

1. Find out how you can.
2. Change your DB design as a FK should have an index and if you can't have one then FKs are probably not the way to go. Maybe have a table of managers and a table of employees?

Comment: that may be a solution, BUT in my case, no 'triggers', no 'alters' allowed. simple 'create table' followed by 'inserts' are only needed. Now?

Comment: @popstack, I had too much to say so I added an edit to the answer.

Comment: Pretty sure you're going to have to define a unique or foreign key constraint for the foreign key constraint to reference.  And you could always omit the `ON DELETE` clause, which functions as would an `ON DELETE RESTRICT` clause in other RDBMS's, preventing deletion of a parent with child records.

Comment: @AdamMusch, you are of course correct about the PK. I've updated the answer. I don't like not doing anything after a delete though; if you don't it provides no benefits over `set null` and will leave you with non-obviously orphaned records in the table.

Comment: @Ben: If you don't specify either `ON DELETE CASCADE` or `ON DELETE SET NULL` in Oracle, it will prevent you from deleting the parent, which prevents the non-obviously orphaned records in the first place by throwing `ORA-02292`.

Answer (score 1):

SELF REFERENCES QUERY...

```
Alter table table_name ADD constraints constraints_name foreign key(column_name1,column_name2..) references table_name(column_name1,column_name2...) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

EX- `ALTER TABLE Employee ADD CONSTRAINTS Fr_key( mgr_no) references employee(Emp_no) ON DELETE CASCADE;`