# like foreign key how to refer another column value in same table for values using oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enforce a constraint of foreign key on columns of same table in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768118/how-to-enforce-a-constraint-of-foreign-key-on-columns-of-same-table-in-sql)

Table1

```
Column1 Column2  Column3 
 1        value  1
 2        value  1
 3        value  2
```

here in a same table column 1 is primary key, but column3 value must be from column1.
How to create table like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your table is already there then you need to run couple of ddl statements

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 
    ( 
     column1 NUMBER (4)  NOT NULL , 
     column2 VARCHAR2(20)  NOT NULL , 
     column3 NUMBER (4) 
    ) 
;


ALTER TABLE TABLE_1 
    ADD CONSTRAINT TABLE_1_PK PRIMARY KEY ( column1) ;



ALTER TABLE TABLE_1 
    ADD CONSTRAINT TABLE_1_TABLE_1_FK FOREIGN KEY 
    ( 

     column3
    ) 
    REFERENCES TABLE_1 
    ( 
     column1
    ) 
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you looking for `self referencing table`

```
create TABLE MyTable
(
   Column1 NUMBER,
   Column2 varchar2(30),
   Column3 NUMBER,
   PRIMARY KEY(column1),
   CONSTRAINT fk_column1_2
    FOREIGN KEY (column3)
    REFERENCES MyTable (column1)

);
```

Comment: you rejected the edit , then it wont work for oracle ....

Comment: of course not because there two mistakes , there is no keyword "table", int won't work for oracle.

Comment: @sunleo Now I see your changes, sorry. I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a CHECK Constraint :

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
 a number,
 b number,
 CONSTRAINT CKAEQUALB CHECK (a = b)
);
```

Comment: it wont work for final case.